# error en script con clave foranea

Tags: msql

```sql
drop table if exists programa;
create table programa (
     id_nº_vuelo serial,
     id_codigo integer ,
     id_modelo varcharacter (110),
     aereolinea varcharacter (15),
     disponibilidad varcharacter (15),
     escala numeric,
primary key (id_nº_vuelo),
FOREIGN KEY (id_codigo) REFERENCES aereopuerto(id_codigo));
```

Me sale esto: ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

```
Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'id_codigo' and referenced column 'id_codigo' in foreign key constraint 'programa_ibfk_1' are incompatible.    0.000 sec
```

Comment: El tipo de dato de id_codigo debe ser el mismo en ambas tablas.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato tiene la columna `id_codigo` en la tabla `aereopuerto`? (ojo que las instalaciones se llaman **Aeropuerto**, sin la segunda E que le estás poniendo al nombre de la entidad).

Comment: Este tipo de nombres => **id_nº_vuelo** no es nada aconsejado. Usa otra nomenclatura. `num_vuelo` o `id_num_vuelo`...

Comment: ¿Es mSQL o MySQL?