# Error al crear la tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Creé esta tabla y me sale un error la intentar poner una clave foránea:

```
drop table if exists aviones;
create table aviones(id_avion varchar (15) not null auto_increment ,
                     codigo varcharacter (15) not null,
                     id_modelo integer not null,
                     capacidad numeric not null,
primary key (id_avion),
foreign key (codigo) references aereopuerto (idcodigo));
```

Me sale esto:

```
Error Code: 1063. Incorrect column specifier for column 'id_avion'  0.000 sec
```

Comment: Y esto no es lo mismo que [ya has preguntado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/600043/error-en-script-con-clave-foranea)??

Comment: ¿`id_avion` no tendría que ser `integer`?...

Answer (score 0):

No puedes declarar la columna del tipo `varchar` y `auto_increment`. Debería ser del tipo `integer`.

Prueba así:

```
drop table if exists aviones;
create table aviones(id_avion integer not null auto_increment ,
                     codigo varchar (15) not null,
                     id_modelo integer not null,
                     capacidad numeric not null,
primary key (id_avion),
foreign key (codigo) references aereopuerto (idcodigo));
```

OJO con la nomenclatura, como ya te han advertido en comentarios a una pregunta similar. El nombre correcto es `aeropuerto`.

Otra cosa, las llaves foráneas deben ser del mismo tipo que la columna a que hacen referencia.

En la tabla `aeropuerto`, la columna `idcodigo` debe ser del tipo `varchar (15)` para que esto funcione: `foreign key (codigo) references aereopuerto (idcodigo)`, si allí la columna es de tipo `integer` (que sería lo lógico), entonces la columna de llave foránea debería definirse así: `codigo integer not null`.

Answer (score 0):

Estas intentando auto incrementar una columna de tipo de dato varchar, la columna id_avion debe ser de tipo integer:

```sql
  drop table if exists aviones;
  create table aviones(
  id_avion integer not null,
  codigo varchar(15) not null,
  id_modelo integer not null,
  capacidad integer not null,
  id_tipo_avion integer not null,
  primary key (id_avion),
  foreign key (codigo) references aereopuerto (idcodigo));
```

Debes ser cuidadoso al asignar un tipo de dato y aplicar la normalizacion a tu base de datos. Puedes leer un poco sobre le tema [aqui](https://bookdown.org/paranedagarcia/database/normalizacion.html).